# Play 2.3 Scala Passing the Request variable : Loses "type" (value asJson is not a member of type parameter A)

Tags: scala, generics, playframework

I can get at the JSON within `Action.async` block, but I would specifically like to "pass" the request parameter to a helper method, `JSONtoCaseClass`; when I do this it loses the `asJson` method.

I have a basic controller - setting a debug break point on the last line here

```scala
def addTeamMember = Action.async {
    implicit request =>
      PimpRequest.JSONtoCaseClass
```

**request.body.asJson = None**

`PimpRequest` is defined as below; setting a debug break point on the last line here

```scala
object PimpRequest {
  implicit val projectReads = Json.reads[Project]

  def JSONtoCaseClass[A](implicit request: Request[A]) = {
    val newJSON = request
```

**request.body.asJson = No such instance field: "asJson"**

Or; to get the compiler to give an error; adding the line

```scala
val newJSONProject =  request.body.asJson.getOrElse(throw new InvalidRequest("No JSON found in request"))
```

Gives

**value asJson is not a member of type parameter A**

So how do help the compiler work out that Request of type A?

Comment: `Action.async(parse.json)` ?

Comment: I can get at the JSON within Action.async, but I would specifically like to "pass" the request parameter to a helper the helper function JSONtoCaseClass; when I do this it loses the asJson method

I've updated the question slightly to try and be clearer on that

Comment: Make JSONToCaseClass only work for json requests maybe? Something like: def JSONToCaseClass(implicit request: Request[AnyContentAsJson])

Comment: That does it! If you would like to put it as an answer I would gladly accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter code here`      def JSONtoCaseClass[A](request: Request[AnyContent])

instead of

```
 def JSONtoCaseClass[A](implicit request: Request[A])
```

(`AnyContent` instead of `A`) means `request.body.asJson` is available